# JavaScript: Using decodeUri or unescape isn't removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm currently loading a WSYWIG editor and reading the HTML code directly from a database.

```
var html = "%3Cp%3E%3Ca%20href=%22google%20 : %20//in-app.purchase%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https%20 : %20//uploads/28/content_drawadragon.png%22%20style=%22height%20 : %20100%25;%20width%20 : %20100%25%22%20/%3E%3C/a%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A"
```

However, using `decodeURI(html)` results in this:

```
"<p><a href="google :  //in-app.purchase"><img src="https  :  //uploads/28/content_drawadragon.png" style="height  :  100%; width  :  100%" /></a></p>"
```

And what I'd really like is this:

```
decodeURI(html) = "<p><a href="google://in-app.purchase"><img src="https: //uploads/28/content_drawadragon.png" style="height:100%;width:100%"/></a></p>"
```

Would love help to try to work this out with as little code as possible without some crazy regex.

Comment: `decodeURI` doesn't remove whitespace. Not sure how this could be done efficiently without a regex. Why does the the input have extra whitespace anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the whitespaces before decodeURI.

The "bad" pattern seems to be an escaped space followed by a space, colon, space and escaped space so use this regexp:

```
decodeURI(html.replace(/%20 : %20/g, ":"))
```